# IllegalAnnotationsException: domain.NewsletterType does not have a no-arg default constructor

Tags: spring, jaxb, resteasy

Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
xxx.tools.newsletter.domain.NewsletterType does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at xxx.tools.newsletter.domain.NewsletterType
        at public xxx.tools.newsletter.domain.NewsletterType xxx.tools.newsletter.domain.Newsletter.getType()
        at xxx.tools.newsletter.domain.Newsletter
        at public xxx.tools.newsletter.domain.Newsletter xxx.commons.user.ws.domain.SweepstakeResponse.getReminderEmail()
        at xxx.commons.user.ws.domain.SweepstakeResponse

```
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:472)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:363)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBContextWrapper.<init>(JAXBContextWrapper.java:74)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBContextWrapper.<init>(JAXBContextWrapper.java:99)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.XmlJAXBContextFinder.createContextObject(XmlJAXBContextFinder.java:51)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBContextFinder.createContext(AbstractJAXBContextFinder.java:129)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.XmlJAXBContextFinder.findCachedContext(XmlJAXBContextFinder.java:42)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.findJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:52)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getMarshaller(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:127)
```

Comment: What does xxx.tools.newsletter.domain.NewsletterType look like?  Does it have a no-arg constructor?

Comment: NO it does not have a  default no-arg constructor. So my question is that, can we solve this problem without defining a no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For classes without a no-arg constructor you can use an XmlAdapter:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a simpler way if the immutable never needs to be unmarshalled from XML? i.e., it is only ever serialized *to* XML.